# How we can handle session management for login users in mobile applications (android,iphone) which dosent include browswes

Tags: php, android, iphone, yii

We are developing an mobile application (android , iphone) which has server side coding in the YII PHP framework. Is there any way to handle login sessions and cookies for mobile devices, or are there any settings which YII supports for handling cookies and sessions for devices?

I think that Yii provides some solution for this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Does your app(s) make HTTP requests to your server or are you talking about WebViews (because you mention cookies). In any case, you may want to take a look at OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are just to most used way to handel the session id, 
the session id could be sent as a GET-parameter if thats 
easier to code in the app.

```
session_id($_GET['session_id']);
```